# Counting the White dots in a Black background

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

After preprocessing a fabric image, I got an output with white dots as follows:

Dot Map

[image: Dot Map]

The aim is to output two numbers i.e.,the number of white dots 1)Via Horizontally and 2)Via Vertically using OPENCV,python.

Challenges:
1.There are some points missing in some rows/columns but the count should be in the row/column with complete set of points.
2.Set of dots are not exactly horizontal/vertical.

PS:1) I have tried connected components(cv2.connectedComponents) to count the total number of dots but it failed because some points are missing and noise adds some points aswell.
2) I tried to count manually looping through rows and columns( by skewing if dotmap is tilted), but it gave a bad result.

How to count them or get a track of tilted dotline?

Comment: Can you share your code for the total count? I don't see any noise in your picture.

Comment: can you explain more about the noise? What kind of noise (e.g. salt & pepper, gaussian, etc) is it?

Comment: @BahmanRouhani I tried erode and dilating the output, then i was able to remove noise as the image above.My main concern is to count along a line either horizontally or vertically.

Comment: @TA , I somehow removed noise at the cost of noise. This is one of the manual ways that i used to count but i need an efficient one                                                                                                      
n=50 # number of loops(random)
count = np.zeros(n)

for i in range(0,a-1,int(a/n)):   #iterate over random n rows
    e =int( i/int(a/n) )   # index of a row(0 - n-1)
    #print(i)
    for j in range(1,b-1):
        
        if filter[i,j] == filter[i,j-1] :
            continue
        else:
            count[e] = count[e]+1

Comment: The only solution that comes to my mind atm is finding first point, the point next to it and the point below it and using these 3 points to obtain an affine transform so your lines are horizontal/vertical. Then you could traverse through the image with fixed steps and notice when a point is missing.